# conceptual Q on @font-face / weight /style

Tags: css, fonts

I've got a quite basic question about the concept of `@font-face`:

When importing a font-face like this (example taken from filament groups font-events/font-loading.html):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    src: url('fonts/sourcesanspro-lightit-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    src: url('fonts/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    src: url('fonts/sourcesanspro-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and in the CSS, I declare something like

```
body {font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';}
em {font-style:italic;}
strong {font-weight: bold;}
```

will the text get rendered with the appropriate font-faces, or will the browser apply `<em>faux-serifs</em>` and `<strong>faux-bold</strong>` on the default, regular Font (Source Sans Pro light in this case)?

If not, could this be "intercepted" somehow?

Thanks to all!

david

Comment: Conceptually, this should work as intended, with no faux bold/italics, since you provided the appropriate faces. I don't know how many browsers actually honor this, though.

Comment: I gave it a first shot, and miserably failed – when the font is declared as "standard" for a certain weight/style, the css fails (the standard-font works, but italics and bold both fall back to the generic whatever-font). will investigate.